# what is the cluster manager used in Databricks ? How do I change the number of executors in Databricks clusters?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

What is the cluster manager used in Databricks?
How do I change the number of executors in Databricks clusters ?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question:

> What is the cluster manager used in Databricks?

I try to dig this information out, but I couldn't find any info about it from the official docs.

It seems like Databricks is not using any of the cluster managers from Spark mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html)

According to [this presentation](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Ematei/courses/2015/6.S897/readings/databricks-mit-slides.pdf), On page 23, it mentions 3 parts of Databricks cluster manager

- Instance manager
- Resource manager
- Spark Cluster manager

So I guess Databricks uses its own pripriotory cluster manager.

Comment: I really hope databricks one day will release this info.